# Why does the diode in this AC circuit activate when $u1(t)$ reaches specifically 3.5V?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

In this circuit I am supposed to create the graph for u2(t) where u1(t)=5*sin(314t) V.

I understand how to get the amplitude of u2(t) and that u2(t) equals the voltage over the 100 ohm resistor when the diode is in reverse bias (open circuit on diode).

But I do not understand why it is specifically at the threshold 3.5V that the diode is in forward bias (making u2(t) equal the voltage of the diode which is assumed by default to be 0.7V).

[image][image]

Comment: assume that the diode is open circuit, when would the voltage across it become 0.7V?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Step 1: Analyze the circuit without the diode. Draw $\hat u_2(t)$
2. Step 2: add the diode by applying $u_2(t) = \min(\hat u_2(t), 0.7V)$